# Text effect display after the page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need the text glowing effect. I found this location.

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/G3J6V/1/

But the client wants to the text effect not on hover but it was change on after the page load.

I do not know jquery, javascript. I spent more times to fix it. But i is failed. Anyone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On page load you could just use the document.ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {

        $(".confirm_selection").animate({
        color: "red"
        }, 2000, function() {

     $(".confirm_selection").animate({
        color: "black"
     }, 2000);        

  });

    },4010);



});​
```

now it starts glowing red on the page load.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am facing one more problem. I used jquery 1.7.2 version. The animation support only jquery 1.6.2 version. So it is not work on my web page. Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: jQuery.fx.off = false; can you try that, putting it at the top of your script

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/G3J6V/113/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".confirm_selection").animate({color: "red"}, 2000).animate({color: "black"}, 2000);
    }, 400);
});​
```

It uses jquery $(document).ready() so basically once everything has loaded it displays the animation. Then i have used setInterval() function to repeat the animation.

or i suggest using something like jQuery `(window)load.()`.

```
(window).load(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".confirm_selection").animate({color: "red"}, 2000).animate({color: "black"}, 2000);
    }, 400);
});
```

Basically when all images and EVERYTHING is loaded it carrys out this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.confirm_selection').animate({
    color: "red"
}, 2000) ;

$('.confirm_selection').animate({
    color: "black"
}, 2000);

});
```

use `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".confirm_selection").animate({
        color: "red"
    }, 2000, '', function() {
    $(".confirm_selection").animate({
        color: "black"
    }, 2000); });
});​
```

The `$(document).ready()` makes the script when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I cannot seem to comment on the above answers, but both Arun and Css Tube above appear to be providing a second anonymous function as an argument to ready(), which doesn't ever get executed, so the text never returns to black.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am facing one more problem. I used jquery 1.7.2 version. The animation support only jquery 1.6.2 version. So it is not work on my web page. Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your problem - JQuery 1.7.2 also supports .animate(). http://api.jquery.com/animate/ states that the method was added in v1.0, and updated in v1.4 and v1.7